# Retrieve Storyboard from Event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, storyboard

I have a generic `Storyboard` defined in my XAML as follows:

```
<Storyboard Core:Key="GenericAnimation" Completed="OnStoryboardCompleted"/>
```

And in my code-behind as follows:

```
m_GenericAnimation = (Storyboard)Resources["GenericAnimation"];
```

Every `Storyboard` of my applications shares the same `Completed` event `OnStoryboardCompleted`. I would like to change a little bit the behavior of my event depending on the animation that is just being completed like so (pseudocode):

```
private void OnStoryboardCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (completedStoryboard == m_GenericAnimation)
        DoSomethingSpecific();

    DoSomethingCommon();
}
```

How can I retrieve the currently completed `Storyboard` from sender? How can I correctly compare two `Storyboard` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Name` property on `Storyboard`:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1" Name="Storyboard1_Name">
    <!-- ... -->
</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard2" Name="Storyboard2_Name">
    <!-- ... -->
</Storyboard>
```

And then:

```
Storyboard sb1, sb2;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    sb1 = (Storyboard)Resources["Storyboard1"];
    sb2 = (Storyboard)Resources["Storyboard2"];

    sb1.Completed += storyboard_Completed;
    sb2.Completed += storyboard_Completed;
}

void storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string StoryBoardName = ((ClockGroup)sender).Timeline.Name;
    if (StoryBoardName == "Storyboard1_Name") { /* DoSomething(); */ }
    if (StoryBoardName == "Storyboard2_Name") { /* DoSomething(); */ }
}
```